# Authorization and associations between user and posts

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm learning Ruby on Rails now, and in the process of learning I'm writing a simple blog. I'm stuck with a certain problem - I need to have two sessions - Admin session, in which an Admin can create, update and delete posts and create/update comments, and a User session, in which User can only create, update and delete HIS OWN comments, so that each post should belong to Admin and display his name, and each comment should belong to a certain User and display his own name (as a method of signing in/up I want a simple form with name, email and password or through Facebook/VK API)

Comment: a little more: Admin can create or update only his own comments, but delete any user's comment, and a regular user can create/update/delete only his own comments

Comment: So, what's the question here?

Comment: @maximf I just can't manage out how to make associations between each user and his actions, I mean, that every comment belongs to certain user and how to make distinction between admin and a regular user :(

Comment: should it be in my models something like
`class Post
    belongs_to :admin
end
class Comment
    belongs_to :current_user
end`
?

Comment: I'd suggest you to go with just one model i.e. `User` and add field `admin: boolean` to this model if that suits your app design.

Comment: @maximf but how I do create a distinct admin session? for example, at signing in/up

Comment: The most common solution is to use something like `devise` to take care of sessions for you, unless you want to implement your own authentication logic.

Comment: Without the overhead of `devise` adding a bit flag to `User` like @maximf suggested will allow you to create method and check if the `current_user` is an admin. e.g. (`current_user.admin?`) Best resource for almost exactly what you are trying to do would be to step through Michael Hartl's Rails tutorial. It will take you through sessions and authentication as well as the associations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key here is understanding the difference between *authorization* and *authentication*.

**Authentication** is being able to verify the identity of the user. This is what Devise solves. This involves logging the user in and out and keeping track of who the current user is.

**Authorization** is who gets to do what in the application. "User can only create, update and delete HIS OWN comments" is clear cut example of a authorization rule.

Most beginners are for some unexplainable reason drawn to the idea of jamming *authorization* into the *authentication* layer. So they set out to try to authenticate a Admin class and Visitor class and the authentication layer ends up like swiss cheese. To fix the first mess they add Single Table Inheritance or MTI which just aggravates the problem.

Instead if you view authorization as a linked but separate concern there is much simpler and tried solution: roles.

The simplest possible solution is using a bitmask (an integer column) together with [ActiveRecord::Enum](http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Enum.html) to denote the users role:

```
class AddRoleToUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :users, :role, :integer, default: 0
    add_index :users, :role
  end
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  enum role: [:user, :admin]
end
```

Which will let you do stuff like `@user.admin?`. This works as long as you have a very simple scenario where roles are application wide and a user can only have a single role. For more complex scenarios you would often setup a `Role` model (pun not intended) and create a one-to-many or many-to-many relationship between users and roles. See the [Rolify](https://github.com/RolifyCommunity/rolify) gem for an example of how this works.

You may want to have a look at some existing solutions for authorization and authentication and figure out how to integrate them before even attempting to reinvent the wheel.

- [The Ruby Toolbox: Rails Authentication](https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/rails_authentication)
- [The Ruby Toolbox: Rails Authorization](https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/rails_authorization)